# How to change the order of columns in a pandas dataframe using a method chain?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

It's easy to change the order of columns in a pandas dataframe using brackets (see below, where I switch the first two columns). However, I cannot find anything about how to do this with a method chain, which is easy in R using `dplyr::select()`. For example, I would like something like: df.reorder_columns(["num_wings","num_legs","num_specimen_seen"]), where "reorder_columns" is a made-up method.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
    df[["num_wings","num_legs","num_specimen_seen"]]
```

I know there are some dplyr copy-cats in the python universe, but I want to avoid those packages since they are considered "bleeding-edge"

Comment: but that will depend on how you want to reorder your columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `.loc` accessor. This works for rows and columns alike.

```py
df = (
  pd.DataFrame({
    'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
    'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]
  }, index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
  .loc[
    ['dog', 'spider', 'falcon', 'fish'], # rows
    ["num_wings", "num_legs", "num_specimen_seen"] # columns
  ]
)
```

Comment: And if you don't need to rearrange the rows you can do 
```df.loc[:, ['num_wings', 'num_legs', 'num_specimen_seen']]```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

columnsNames = ['num_wings', 'num_legs', 'num_specimen_seen']

df.reindex(columns=columnsNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just use `sorted` method to sort columns order:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'c_num_legs_2': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'b_num_wings_1': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'a_num_specimen_seen_3': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

cols_reorder = sorted(df.columns, key=lambda col: col.rsplit('_')[-1])
df[cols_reorder]
```

```py
print(cols_reorder)
# ['b_num_wings_1', 'c_num_legs_2', 'a_num_specimen_seen_3']



print(df.sort_index(axis=1))
        a_num_specimen_seen_3  b_num_wings_1  c_num_legs_2
falcon                     10              2             2
dog                         2              0             4
spider                      1              0             8
fish                        8              0             0



print(df.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False))
       c_num_legs_2  b_num_wings_1  a_num_specimen_seen_3
falcon             2              2                     10
dog                4              0                      2
spider             8              0                      1
fish               0              0                      8
```